# Maxmemory Samples in Redis

Tags: redis, lru

I am using "maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru"for key eviction in REDIS. REDIS picks the keys randomly for eviction.Is there a way to see the random sample picked by the REDIS for eviction of key.

Answer (score 0):

Redis does not picks the keys randomly, but applied a LRU (Least Recently Used) algorithms to choose the keys to evict.

However, it applies an LRU on a sample, to save time and memory. This is the purpose of the maxmemory-samples setting. No, I don't think you can see those specific sample.

If you really want to know which keys were evicted, you can (not in production) use the KEYS command and check which keys were evicted.

Comment: I know it is used for LRU. I want to see the sample picked by REDIS for LRU.